# How can I grab a value from another sheet based on an ID

Tags: excel, vlookup

---

Customer

```
| Cus ID | Cus Name |
| 1      | Bob      |
| 2      | Sam      |
| 3      | Tom      |
```

---

Transaction

```
| TID | Cus ID | Cus Name |
| 1   | 1      | ???      |
| 2   | 2      | ???      |
| 3   | 1      | ???      |
| 4   | 3      | ???      |
```

---

Essentially my question is, how can I grab the `Cus Name` Using the `Cus ID` in the `Transaction` sheet?

Comment: ^^ this ^^ and microsoft even has a video for you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard `VLOOKUP`. In cell `C1`

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,Customer!A:B,2,0)
```

Drop formula down to used range to fill column.